# Getting an "warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast" error

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Below is my MRE. Essentially, I am making a board game, and I need to do two things. Make the board, and after each turn, print it. Since the board changes after each turn, I have them in two separate functions `makeBoard` and `printBoard` below, I just put them in the MRE. The board also gets its dimensions from `args` and so it can be any size that the player chooses. But when I print out the empty board, it says the error mentioned above.

for context the matrix is supposed to be a 5 by 5 then it should print like this:

. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .

edit: I can not test if the matrix prints with the correct formatting since I am getting this error, so if there are issues with that part of the code, I will take care of them later.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    
    char board[5][5];
     
     // this is where I am filling the board with its 'null' values
     for(int i =0; i<x; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<y; j++){
            // this is where the error takes place
            board[i][j]= ".";
        }
    }
    // this is where I am printing the board, I have a specific format so, 
    // that there is a space between each dot
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<y; j++){
            if(j<y-1){
                printf("%c",board[i][j]);
                printf(" ");
            }
            else if(j=y-1){
                printf("%c", board[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you are deliberately trying to make your life difficult, you might consider better names than `x`, `y`, and `i` & `j`. The usual _convention_ is that `x` is horizontal and `y` is vertical. Your print loop seems to be iterating _vertically_ **inside** a _horizontal_ iteration. That's not how it will appear on the screen.. (And, as presented, there's a LF between each dot, too...)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line

```c
board[i][j]=".";
```

you should have written:

```c
board[i][j]='.';
```

Double quotes(`"`) are used for string literals, and single quotes(`'`) are used for characters.

You get this warning because strings are stored as pointers to the first character(`char*`). The characters inside of strings are stored in memory addressed from the value of the pointer used to store strings to the first null character `'\0'` after the first one in the string(in memory).

Also, a warning isn't an error. Errors prevent code from getting compiled, while warnings notify of potential problems with the code.

Note: Use `unsigned int` instead of `int` for indexes because `int` is `signed` by default.

Comment: ah, okay, thank you very much, a very minor oversight that definitely matters.